# XBMC - show movie titles in german?

Tags: kodi

I use XBMC to sort my movies. All the movies are named using their original (mostly english) title and I would like it to show the titles in german.

I already set XBMC language to german and rescanned the movie library, but the titles are still shown in english.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If it is an English movie then the title will show in English since that is the proper name of it.  If you want the movie title to show in German then you will have to manually edit the nfo file.  In between the `<title></title>` type the German version of the title and then save the file.

Here is additional information about the [**NFO files**](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=NFO_files/Movies).

Per Jack's suggestion you could also use a media manager program such as one of the following:

- [**Media Companion**](http://mediacompanion.codeplex.com/)
- [**MediaElch**](http://www.mediaelch.de/)
- [**YAYMan**](http://mediaplayersite.com/YAYMan)
- [**Ember Media Manager**](http://goo.gl/WrRJ7)

Comment: Here's the application that I used to edit the information for my movies in XBMC, granted I'm using it with a MySQL database.

http://www.mediaelch.de/

Comment: You can open the nfo file directly via notepad and edit the title without having to use any other program

Comment: Linger, that is true. But I was just suggesting something that I use to create the NFO files to begin with. Editing one with Notepad is easy enough, but if you're going to mass-edit them or create a bunch of them, a purpose-built application is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your library definition (screen where you define folder X has to be scrapped by service Y). Instead of pressing "OK" look for "Parameters". It then offers a preferred language, english is the default.

[image: Screengrab from the scrapper settings]

More info on the Kodi wiki "[Set conternt and scan](http://kodi.wiki/view/Set_content_and_scan)"

Comment: Note that this will only affect newly added content. To update existing films, either remove and readd the source (forcing a rescan of everything), or after changing the language for the source you can right-click each film → *Movie information* → *Refresh*